# ODS library for octave OSX

Tags: homebrew, octave, ods

I have to read an ODS data file in octave. After some search I knew that I should use the ods library for octave but I don't know how to install it.
So how to install ods library for octave using brew on OSX?

Comment: you need the Octave forge io package.

Comment: Homebrew doesn’t provide ods.

Comment: I managed to install the package but it doesn't parse the files well because there are alot of jars missing! Although I added them using the javaaddpath from octave as mentioned in the documentation!

Comment: to handle ods files, you will need to have libreoffice installed somewhere and as you already found out, configure the javaclasspath. You should read http://wiki.octave.org/IO_package#ODS_support and ask on the Octave help mailing list as otherwise, this question is off-topic here in StackOverflow.